# How to get Core Data to make only one instance of entity of type

Tags: macos, core-data, singleton, status

So.  Before I get singleton pattern hate on this message hear me out.  I'd love to hear ideas.   I'm making a program that I think I need to use core data for, because later I want the status of some variables to be easily accessible from OS X, and multiple iOS devices.

What I'm making is an OS X program that will control phidgets (phidgets.com) to control and listen for status changes in real world objects.  Example:  whether a motor is turned on or not.  Turn a motor on and off.  Turn on status lights, etc.

I originally thought I'd just make global variables that I change, poll and manipulate in order to have a central status board for the logic of the program to work off of.  But, because of the engineering that is put into core data every year by apple, I am assuming making this work with core data will allow me to more easily have options to sync this later with iOS devices that could control or monitor the said status' remotely.

Is there a nifty way you can imagine to:

-startup the program, confirm there is only one entity of type "SystemStatus", if there isn't one, make one.  is there is one, we continue and are able to let the program update it's attributes with status of the real world objects it's controlling.

using core data was something I thought of also, because it will allow me a place to persist stored history of data gathered too. Example:  motor bearing temperature over time.

Answer (score 0):

If you ensure that access to this object is done through your API, Core Data becomes an implementation detail behind the getter method of the singleton object. There are no facilities in Core Data to tell it to create only one object, but if you ensure access to the object is done through a wrapper of your own, you can fetch it on demand and if it doesn't exist, you can insert it, save, and pass it to the caller.

An important thing to consider when using Core Data objects is multithreading. Passing the same object to multiple threads is very error-prone and requires locking mechanisms (or use of Apple's block-based API). This is not very straightforward for what you describe. Consider either a wrapper object which uses Core Data objects internally (wraps access to properties in block-based API) or using a different approach than Core Data.

Comment: so, you're proposing adding my own api wrapper to make it so, my multithreading communicates with my api wrapper and not directly to the core data methods?  something like this?:  http://natashatherobot.com/ios-core-data-singleton-example/

Comment: Not really, this is a single instance of the Core Data stack, so you may very well need this also, but what I meant was a wrapper around core Data that will give you the functionality of `SystemStatus`.

Comment: might is ask for a small example of how this wrapper would be implemented.  I'm not quite seeing it.